# 12 DC Power 3.5A to TV via Antenna Cable

Tags: power, coax

I am looking for a single connection to a TV which is powered by 12Vdc 3.5A Max, I would like to power the TV via the coaxial cable and also use the coax cable as an antenna input.

I am looking for two separate circuits to accomplish the following.. using a common cable from antenna running to several other TV's coupling 12VDC on that cable without affecting the other TV's then running the coax with RF to another TV, decoupling the 12VDC which will power that TV via a separate connector and then continue to use the cable to the TV for antenna input..

Comment: *I would like to power the TV via the coaxial cable* - sounds troublesome.

Comment: Not sure how far you're planning to run the cable but I reckon you'll lose about half a volt per metre at that level of current.

Comment: cable run of approximately 18" thru this unit....https://www.fpmarine.com/Flat-screen-TV-mounting-bracket-p/mntbrkt%2010001tvmountbrkt.htm

Answer (score 1):

The circuit is called a "bias tee" and it's easily found (and it's the same circuit for both ends — it has three ports: RF, DC, and RF+DC, and it works as well for combining as it does for splitting). Conceptually it's just an inductor and a capacitor, with appropriate values, and careful construction to avoid impedance mismatches that would distort the RF signal.

For the TVs that don't need power, you could use the same circuit and leave the DC port disconnected, or you could use a simple capacitor as a DC-block.

However, this may not work out as well as you want. Your average TV coax has an 18awg or 20awg center conductor, and a resistance of 10 to 40 mΩ / meter. If we suppose it's 20mΩ and your run is 30m, then at 3.5 A you're looking at a voltage drop of around 2 volts, and you're dissipating more than 7 watts in the cable. You can step up the supply voltage to around 14V to account for the drop, but it will do nothing to help with the power lost in the cable (and, if the TV draws less than the max 3.5 amps, it will see something closer to 14V, which might make it unhappy).

Comment: Hello Hobbs, Thank you.. This is wat I found based on your feedback https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B07X219P5M/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o00_s01?ie=UTF8&psc=1

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B074K51D7X/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1  the cable run with 12V is only 18" so I do not anticipate much of a voltage drop on RG59 Cable which is 49ohms / 1000' DC resistance 75ohm impedance

Comment: @ChrisLewis not sure if that one is big enough to handle 3.5A but it might be. In any case good luck :)